# Can I submit a manuscript to arxiv while it is under review in a journal?

Tags: journals, arxiv, peer-review

My paper is under review in an Elsevier journal. It has been over a month and it's still in review stage. It might take another month for the reviews to come back. I should have submitted it to arxiv before submitting to the journal. However, is it too late to submit it now to arxiv?

The journal is "Additive Manufacturing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Elsevier article sharing policies](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing)

> Authors can share their preprint anywhere at any time.

So yes you can put your article on the arXiv.

Comment: And more generally, most journals will require you not to submit to other journals, but that doesn't imply any broader requirements not to disseminate preprint versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the journal's policy about this. If not specified, ask the contact person for the journal. In sociology this practice is widely accepted, but I suppose there are disciplinary and/or publishers' differences.